# Add D3 V4 chart styles to a separate css file with angular-cli

Tags: javascript, d3.js, angular, charts, angular-cli

I am using D3 charting library to create charts with Angular-cli. D3 version is **4.2.2**. Following is what I am trying.

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import * as D3 from 'd3';

    import {ChartComponent} from './chart/chart.component'

    @Component({
      moduleId: module.id,
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],

      directives: [ChartComponent]
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'app works!';

      constructor() {
        console.log(D3);
      }
    }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-chart></app-chart>
```

**chart.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {BarGraphDirective} from './bar-graph.directive';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-chart',
  templateUrl: 'chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['chart.component.css'],
  directives: [BarGraphDirective]
})
export class ChartComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

**chart.component.html**

```
<bar-graph width="400" height="150" ></bar-graph>
```

Then here is code segment to add tooltip for data point of the chart.

**BarGraphDirective**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer} from '@angular/core';
import * as D3 from 'd3';

@Directive({
  selector: 'bar-graph'
})

export class BarGraphDirective {

  // private data:Array<number>;  // raw chart data
  private htmlElement:HTMLElement;

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
    this.htmlElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement;  // reference to <bar-graph> element from the main template
    console.log(this.htmlElement);
    console.log(D3);

    let d3:any = D3;

    var data = [{
      "date": "2016-10-01",
      "sales": 110,
      "searches": 67
    }, ...];

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 80,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // parse the date / time
    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
    var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%e %B");

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    .
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
    var sales = function (d) {
      return d["sales"];
    }
    var searches = function (d) {
      return d.searches;
    }

    // define the line
    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .y(function (d) {
        return y(d.sales);
      });

    var svg = d3.select(this.htmlElement).append("svg")
      .attr("class", "bar-graph")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
      .style("opacity", 0);

    // format the data
    data.forEach(function (d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
      return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
      return d.sales > d.searches ? d.sales : d.searches;
    })]);

    // Add the line path.
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("d", line(data))
      .style("stroke", "orange")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px");

    // change line to look at searches
    line.y(function (d) {
      return y(d.searches);
    });

    // Add the second line path.
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("d", line(data))
      .style("stroke", "steelblue")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px");

    // Add sales to the scatterplot
    svg.selectAll(".sales-circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr('class', 'sales-circle')
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return y(d.sales);
      })
      .style("fill", "orange");

    // Add searches to the scatterplot
    svg.selectAll(".searches-circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4)
      .attr('class', 'searches-circle')
      .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return x(d.date);
      })
      .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return y(d.searches);
      })
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        tooltip.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .9);
        tooltip.html(formatTime(d["date"]) + "<br/> Searches: " + d["searches"])
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px")
          .classed("tooltip", true);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function (d) {
        tooltip.transition()
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      });

    // draw legend
    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
      });

    // draw legend colored rectangles
    legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

    // draw legend text
    legend.append("text")
      .style("font", "14px open-sans")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function (d) {
        return d;
      });

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .style("font", "14px open-sans")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d/%m")));

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .style("font", "14px open-sans")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Add Axis labels
    svg.append("text")
      .style("font", "14px open-sans")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (-margin.left / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")rotate(-90)")
      .text("Sales / Searches");

    svg.append("text")
      .style("font", "14px open-sans")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height + (margin.bottom)) + ")")
      .text("Date");
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.highlight('yellow');
  }
  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.highlight(null);
  }
  private highlight(color: string) {
    let d3:any = D3;
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(d3.select('tooltip'), 'backgroundColor', color);
  }
}
```

Then I updated **chart.component.css** as below.

```
app-chart bar-graph line .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Now the problem is tooltip styles not applied.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can:

So instead of

```
tooltip.html(formatTime(d["date"]) + "<br/> Searches: " + d["searches"])
  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("width", "90px")
  .style("height", "50px")
  .style("padding", "2px")
  .style("text-align", "center")
  .style("font", "14px open-sans")
  .style("background", "lightsteelblue")
  .style("border", "0px")
  .style("border-radius", "8px")
  .style("pointer-events", "none");
```

You can do  `.classed("myStyle", true)` you will need to define `myStyle` in the css:

```
tooltip.html(formatTime(d["date"]) + "<br/> Searches: " + d["searches"])
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px")
      .classed("myStyle", true);
```

Comment: Do I need to define **myStyle** in app.component.css file ?

Comment: yeah or in the main css file both should work...though i have not tried it.

Comment: I have updated my question. Could you please have a look? I tried as your answer. But seems like css styles not applied to the tooltip. Looking forward hearing from you.

Comment: I am sure your `app.component.css` never got loaded..otherwise the style should have applied..try adding in the main css if you have any

Comment: I am not using main.css. I have added **styleUrls: ['chart.component.css'],** in chart.component.ts file. May be I am not correctly set css. May be it cannot find **app-chart bar-graph line .tooltip**

Comment: Kindly note I added css styles to chart.component.css

Comment: yeah i know the problem is about the css not getting loaded may be you can see  if there is a file load failure in network tab. If the style is not up then naturally the style wont be applied..

Comment: chart.component.css file is loaded, there is no any failure in network tab